# Cryptic Spray Json error message

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

I'm receiving the following error message when trying to parse some json:

```
[info]   The future returned an exception of type: spray.httpx.PipelineException, with message: 
Vector("eba760a81b177051b0520418b4e10596955adb98196c15367a2467ab66a19b5c", 600, "AN51SPP6iZBHFJ3aux1jtn6MMMD13Gh3t7", 500,
 ["1BXVXP82f7x9YWdWuCaCYwad8ZoYayyRYt"], "76a91473758c13a91699376abb8fe76931bdd9bdc04ee388ac", false)
 (of class scala.collection.immutable.Vector). (AddressUnspentTXORequestTest.scala:14)
```

and I'm not really sure what that means. Here is the piece of json that I am trying to parse:

```
[
  {
    "transaction_hash": "eba760a81b177051b0520418b4e10596955adb98196c15367a2467ab66a19b5c",
    "output_index": 1,
    "value": 600,
    "asset_id": "AN51SPP6iZBHFJ3aux1jtn6MMMD13Gh3t7",
    "asset_quantity": 500,
    "addresses": [
      "1BXVXP82f7x9YWdWuCaCYwad8ZoYayyRYt"
    ],
    "script_hex": "76a91473758c13a91699376abb8fe76931bdd9bdc04ee388ac",
    "spent": false,
    "confirmations": 31674
  },
  {
    "transaction_hash": "1f9f6224bee8813135aba622693c78a33b3460e4efdb340174f87fdd8c9d4148",
    "output_index": 1,
    "value": 600,
    "asset_id": "AS6tDJJ3oWrcE1Kk3T14mD8q6ycHYVzyYQ",
    "asset_quantity": 200000,
    "addresses": [
      "1BXVXP82f7x9YWdWuCaCYwad8ZoYayyRYt"
    ],
    "script_hex": "76a91473758c13a91699376abb8fe76931bdd9bdc04ee388ac",
    "spent": false,
    "confirmations": 35895
  }
]
```

and here is the case class that I am trying to parse it into:

```
case class UnspentTXO(transaction_hash: String, output_index: Int, value: Long,
  asset_id: Option[String], asset_quantity: Option[Long], addresses: List[BitcoinAddress],
  script_hex: String, spent: Boolean)
```

The method initiating the request is here :

```
  def getUnspentTXOs(address: Address): Future[List[UnspentTXO]] = {
    val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[List[UnspentTXO]] = 
      sendReceive ~> unmarshal[List[UnspentTXO]]
    pipeline(Get(host + path + address.value + "/unspents"))
  }
```

and finally this is how I am parsing that Json Request:

```
override def read(value: JsValue): UnspentTXO = {

  val Seq(transaction_hash, output_index, locked_satoshies, asset_id, asset_quantity, addresses, script_hex, spent) =
    value.asJsObject.getFields("transaction_hash", "value", "asset_id", "asset_quantity", "addresses", "script_hex", "spent")

  val assetId = asset_id match {
    case JsString(s) => Some(s)
    case JsNull => None
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Asset id should be of type JsString or JsNull, got something else")
  }

  val assetQuantity = asset_quantity match {
    case JsNumber(n) => Some(n.toLong)
    case JsNull => None
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Asset quantity should  be JsNull or a JsNumber")
  }

  // convert JsArray to List[ BitcoinAdress ]
  val addressList = addresses match {
    case ja: JsArray => {
      ja.elements.toList.map( e => BitcoinAddress(e.convertTo[String]))
    }
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("address list should be of type JsArray, got something else")
  }

  UnspentTXO(transaction_hash.convertTo[String], output_index.convertTo[Int], locked_satoshies.convertTo[Long],
    assetId, assetQuantity, addressList,
    script_hex.convertTo[String], spent.convertTo[Boolean])

}
```

I think the problem might be that the request is returning a json array instead of just a JSON object, so I am not sure if I am handling that correctly inside of my `getUnspentTXOs`. The error message seems to be very vague. It seems that spray is trying to wrap the json fields inside of a `Vector` instead of inside of a `UnspentTXO` case class. I'm not sure of why this is happening though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just call `convertTo[ Option[ Long ] ]` and `convertTo[ List [ BitcointAddress ] ]`.

This is how `convertTo` is defined,

```
def convertTo[T :JsonReader]: T = jsonReader[T].read(this)
```

Which means... only types `T` for which an `implicit` evidence of `typeclass` `JsonReader[ T ]` is available can be used with `convertTo`.

Unless you provide appropriate `implicit typeclass` evidence, you will have to specially handle few cases.

Other than this, `spray-json` is just too minimalistic... so that so `JsObject` is just a wrapper on top of `Map[ String, JsValue]` and `getFields` is defined as,

```
 def getFields(fieldNames: String*): immutable.Seq[JsValue] =
   fieldNames.flatMap(fields.get)(collection.breakOut)
```

Which means... it will just ignore asked fields which are not present in them map, and only return a sequence of `JsValue`'s corresponding to the asked fields which are present.

Hence optional values have to be checked to be present in the map. Or we will have to pattern-match for each possible case ( which can result in a lot of cases).

```
override def read(value: JsValue): UnspentTXO = {

  val jsObject = value.asJsObject

  // get only non-optional values here 
  val Seq( transaction_hash, output_index, locked_satoshies, addresses,
          script_hex, spent ) =
    jsObject.getFields( "transaction_hash", "output_index", "value", "addresses", "script_hex", "spent" )

  // Assuming you have imported spray.json._, simple types will work.

  // have to handle options differently
  // or 2 optional values would mean 4 patterns-matchings of sequences like above.

  // jsObject.fields is just a Map[ String, JsValue ]

  val assetId = jsObject.fields.get( "asset_id" ) match {
    case Some( JsString( s ) ) => Some( s ) 
    case None => None
  }

  val assetQuantity = jsObject.fields.get( "asset_quantity" ) match {
    case Some( JsNumber( n ) ) => Some( n.toLong ) 
    case None => None
  }

  // convert JsArray to List[ BitcoinAdress ]
  val addressList = addresses match {
    case ja : JsArray => { 
      ja.elements.toList.map( BitcoinAddress( _.convertTo[ String ] ) )
    }
  }

  UnspentTXO( transaction_hash.convertTo[ String ], output_index.convertTo[ Int ],
    locked_satoshies.convertTo[ Long ], assetId, assetQuantity,
    addressList, script_hex.convertTo[ String ], spent.convertTo[ Boolean ] ) 

}
```

Another way to get `convertTo[ Option[ T ] ]` and `convertTo[ List[ T ] ]` working is by importing `spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._` which provides json-formats for most generally used types. But even then, you must have an `implicit` evidence of `typeclass JsonReader[ T ]` in your scope.

Comment: This did not work, I've updated the OP to what I have in my `read` method now. I am still receiving the exact same error.

Comment: Fixed it now... I really did not think that `spray-json` would be such a bare-bone thin wrapper.

Comment: So this is still not working. Couple things to note is that `JsArray[JsValue]` gives me an error saying that `JsArray` cannot be parameterized. I am using spray-json versoin `1.3.1` if that helps.

Comment: I'm also getting the exact same error message I started with.

Comment: Yup that `JsArray[JsValue]` was my mistake... change it to just `JsArray`. Rest of it was working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I am assuming that we have a constructor `BitcoinAddress( address: String)` for `BitcoinAddress`. Try it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71895/discussion-between-chris-stewart-and-sarvesh-kumar-singh).